# List elements are not separating when using a function to do so

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm working on some code to scrape paragraphs from websites. While the code is a bit messy and confusing I think its still legible.

The only thing is I've ran into ONE big roadblock while writing it. When the paragraphs are written out it seems they are conjoined to the paragraphs from that page, i want each paragraphs as its separate list element without being part of a smaller list inside the main list.

My desired output is the top paragraphs that are the most related to the query. I already have all the stuff to check what paragraphs for their reliability to the query but like I said all the paragraphs from one page seem to be grouping together when I write them out to a txt file to check.

Here's my code:

```
#qresultsl is a list of links
for xa in range(0, qresultsl):
    URL=ALLresults[xa].format()
    URL=str(URL)
    URL=URL.replace("'","")
    URL=URL.replace("[","")
    URL=URL.replace("]","")
    pageURL=URL
    try:
        pr=requests.get(pageURL, headers=headers)
    except:
            print("Couldn't scrape ",pageURL)
            continue
    if pr.status_code==200:
        try:
            psoup=BeautifulSoup(pr.text, 'html.parser')
            paragraphs=[''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in
            psoup.findAll('p')]
            presults.append(paragraphs)
        except:
            print("Couldn't scrape ", pageURL)
            continue
    else:
            print("Couldn't scrape ",pageURL)
            continue
# Results

print("\r")
print(len(presults)," websites scraped of ", numresults)
print(len(presults)," pages of content ready for next phase of processing.")

paraList = []
for i in presults:
    #make all keywords one big list
    paraList = sum(presults, [])

presults = paraList
    
cleanparagraphs=[]
rangenum=len(presults)
print(presults)
def cleanresults():
  ct=0
  for dd in range(0,rangenum):
    cleaned=presults[ct]
    cleaned=str(cleaned)
    cleaned=cleaned.replace("/","")
    cleaned=cleaned.replace("]","")
    cleaned=cleaned.replace("[","")
    cleaned=cleaned.replace("'","")
    cleaned=cleaned.replace("\n","")
    NEWITEM=cleaned
    ct=ct+1
    cleanparagraphs.append(NEWITEM)
cleanresults()

presults = cleanparagraphs

paragraphs = []

for z in range(len(presults)):
    pagei=presults[z]
    pagei=str(pagei)
    pagei=pagei.replace("[","")
    pagei=pagei.replace("'","")
    pagei=pagei.replace("]","")
    pageHtml = pagei #i wasn't "stupid". 
    paragraphs.append(presults[z])
'''with open('paragraphs.txt', 'r') as f:
    paragraphs = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
'''
'''for i in paragraphs:
    #make all paragraphs one big list
    paragraphs = sum(paragraphs, [])'''
resultspara=[]
for le in paragraphs: 
    if le not in resultspara: 
        resultspara.append(le) 
paragraphs=resultspara
og=len(presults)
nl=len(paragraphs)
removed=og-nl
print(removed, " duplicates removed")
lst = []
cp=0
for para in paragraphs:
    lst.append(paragraphs[cp].lower())
    cp=cp+1
rem=str(lst)
rem=rem.replace("\r","")
rem=rem.replace("\n","")
rem=rem.replace('"\r\n','')
final_list=rem.split("#####")
phrase1 = query
phrase2 = query2
phrase3 = query3
phrase4 = query4
paragraphs=final_list

ammntRemoved = 0
for i in paragraphs:
    if len(i) < 20:
        paragraphs.remove(i)
        ammntRemoved = ammntRemoved + 1
print("removed " + str(ammntRemoved) + " small lines")

randomVariable = []
for i in paragraphs:
    randomVariable = sum(paragraphs, [])

paragraphs = randomVariable
def getRelated(phrase):
    splitWords = phrase.split() #split the sentence for proccessing
    associatedWords = [splitWords] #add spitwords to associatedWords; associatedWords will be     the main variable to add processed words to
    finalWords = [] #created the variable that will have the final parsde and deduped list 
    
    for word in splitWords:
        #get associated words for each word in the phrase
        html = requests.get("https://api.wordassociations.net/associations/v1.0/json/search?apikey=8c124543-3a0d-4ac9-b6b4-cda92d7d1411&text="+ word + "&lang=en")
        theJson = html.text
        source = json.loads(theJson)
        try:
            associatedWords.append([source["response"][0]["items"][0]["item"],source["response"][0]["items"][1]["item"],source["response"][0]["items"][2]["item"],source["response"][0]["items"][3]["item"],source["response"][0]["items"][4]["item"],source["response"][0]["items"][5]["item"]])
            numass=len(associatedWords)
            print(numass, " associations found for ", word)
        except:
                print("tested word - " + word + " - had no asocciations")
    
    for i in associatedWords:
        #make all keywords one big list
        finalWords = sum(associatedWords, [])
    
    relatedKeywords = []
    for word in finalWords:
        #make finalwords lowercase
        relatedKeywords.append(word.lower())
        return finalWords
#took that out and replaced it with a for loop that does them all beforehand
phrase1 = getRelated(query)
phrase2 = getRelated(query2)
phrase3 = getRelated(query3)
phrase4 = getRelated(query4)

topic = {}
subHead1 = {}
subHead2 = {}
subHead3 = {}

def getGoodParagraphs(keywords, dictionary):
    global length
    for para in paragraphs:
        #get the keyword frequencies in each paragraph
        x = 0
        for keyword in keywords:
            added = para.count(keyword)
            x = x + added
            dictionary[para] = x

#get the lengths of used paragraphs
length = 0
length1 = 0
length2 = 0
length3 = 0

def getLen(lengthVar, dictionary):
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            #count the number of words
            lengthVar = lengthVar + len(dictionary[i].split())
        except:
            #break if theres no more paragraphs in said list
            break
    
getGoodParagraphs(phrase1, topic)
getGoodParagraphs(phrase2, subHead1)
getGoodParagraphs(phrase3, subHead2)
getGoodParagraphs(phrase4, subHead3)

getLen(length, topic)
getLen(length1, subHead1)
getLen(length2, subHead2)
getLen(length3, subHead3)

#sort paragraphs least to greatest
topic = sorted(topic, key=lambda k: topic[k], reverse=True)
subHead1 = sorted(subHead1, key=lambda k: subHead1[k], reverse=True)
subHead2 = sorted(subHead2, key=lambda k: subHead2[k], reverse=True)
subHead3 = sorted(subHead3, key=lambda k: subHead3[k], reverse=True)

def appendTop10(inputList, outputList):
    try:
        for i in range(3):
            outputList.append(inputList[i])
    except:
            print("> Wasnt able to append all 3 paragraphs")

finalTopic = []
finalSubHead1 = []
finalSubHead2 = []
finalSubHead3 = []

appendTop10(topic, finalTopic)
appendTop10(subHead1, finalSubHead1)
appendTop10(subHead2, finalSubHead2)
appendTop10(subHead3, finalSubHead3)

with open("article.txt", "w") as outputFile:
  count=0
  count2=0
  count3=0
  count4=0
  for i in finalTopic:   
      filename = 'text.txt'
      with open(filename, mode="w") as outfile:  # also, tried mode="rb"
          for s in finalTopic:
              outfile.write("%s\n" % s)
          for s in finalSubHead1:
              outfile.write("%s\n" % s)
          for s in finalSubHead2:
              outfile.write("%s\n" % s)
          for s in finalSubHead3:
              outfile.write("%s\n" % s)
print("DONE")
```

What am I doing wrong to not have the top paragraphs sorted for each category?

I'm in desperate need for help, thanks a ton in advance

Comment: Could you cut the code to a minimal reproducable example? This contains a lot of unnecessary extra

Comment: ill cut some stuff off sorry

Comment: Thanks, no worries

Comment: i cut off alot of the top, from then on i try and clean the paragraphs and process them

Comment: @ironkey what is `URL` value

Comment: URL is the website URL that will be scraped

Comment: for example: an article like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_colonization_of_the_Americas

Comment: most of the links are not wikipedia btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do something like this:

```
page_name = []

for paragraph in page:
   page_name.append(paragraph)
```

You could then output each paragraph by printing each list:

```
for page in page_name:
   print(page)
```

Comment: i did that with:
`randomVariable = []
for i in paragraphs:
    randomVariable = sum(paragraphs, [])

paragraphs = randomVariable`

Comment: I could be mistaken but aren't triple quotes multi-line string literals?

Comment: Also, you might want to take out sum and just append each paragraph to a list with the name of the website or page you're scraping

Comment: Hm, probably not your list work then.
Maybe you should write out a delimiter in your file writes, so add an additional output that is easy to parse like ---- to the end of the paragraph.